# Unable to export and import custom block type fields

Tags: 8, configuration

I have created a new custom block type and added some fields to it.
I am able to export and import the custom block type in another Drupal instance via configuration management, but there are no fields.

How do I import the fields too?

Answer (score 2):

The field definitions are in their own yml-files. To check this, export the full archive and search for the dependencies. For example the body of the block content type `basic` has this yml-file:

```
field.field.block_content.basic.body.yml
```

and there you find the dependencies for the block content type:

```
dependencies:
  config:
    - block_content.type.basic
```

Comment: I did not get you. What have to done for field migration along with custom block type.

Comment: You have to export and import `field.field.block_content.[custom_block_type].*.yml`

Comment: I have exported and imported the same, i got the custom block type but not the fields added to it.

Comment: You also need the field.storage definitions and the form_display and view_display configurations. There are some existing rather detailed answers already for that topic. They are for nodes, but it's the same.